# Adding css style to button while popover is open. Remove it when it closes

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Im trying to use an `fa-cog` as a button that opens a popover in AngularJS using Angular UI. I realise this is possible using js/jQuery, but I am looking for a css/html solution.

HTML:

```
<span
        class="fa fa-cog fa-2x"
        uib-popover-template="'popoverTemplate.html'"></span>
```

CSS:

```
fa.cog{
    color: grey;
}

fa.cog:hover{
    color: black;
}
//Doesn't work
fa.cog :active or :focus or :target etc.{
    color: black
}
```

What I am trying to do is, when the popover is not showing, the cog should have the color grey. When the popover is open, the cog should be black.

I've tried css selectors like `fa-cog:active` and `fa-cog:focus`, but they didn't do much.

Unsure how i can achieve this, any ideas?

Comment: you could do it with js - add a class when you toggle the popop?

Comment: true, but i would prefer a css solution, if possible. Editing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popover directive has a helper attribute called `tooltip-is-open`, it provides you with a read-only variable that tell you if the popover is open or not.

Then you can use either `ngClass` or `ngStyle` to conditionally apply your css

```
<span class="fa fa-cog fa-2x"
    uib-popover-template="'popoverTemplate.html'"
    popover-is-open="iAmOpen"
    ng-class="{'active': iAmOpen}">
</span>
```

Comment: Thx, this is perfect. Managed to make it work with :active and :focus if i used a `button` instead of `span`. But there was a bug where it stayed `black` if the user closed the popover clicking on the button again

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
fa.cog{
    color: grey;
}

fa.cog:hover{
    color: black;
}

fa.cog:active, fa.cog:focus{
    color: grey;
}
```

you are setting black color when active or focused, not grey

Comment: Doesn't work with `<span>`. Kinda works with `<button>` though it has a bug where if you close the popover by clicking the button again, it will stay black.